# Make a synchronous HTTP call with RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit, objective-c-blocks

When logging a user into my application I need to pull a user object down from the server using only the username. This returns the userId (among other things) that I need in order to make other API calls. From that point I'll make a couple other HTTP calls using the userId. How can I make a synchronous call to completely pull down the user object before sending the other calls?

I've setup my object mapping in my app delegate class, which works perfectly, and am using this code to pull the user object down from the server:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[@"/api/users/" stringByAppendingString:[_userNameField text]] delegate:self];
```

This is what I've tried... as suggested here: [Making synchronous calls with RestKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325181/making-synchronous-calls-with-restkit)

```
RKObjectLoader* loader = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectLoaderForObject:currentUser method:RKRequestMethodPUT delegate:nil];
RKResponse* response = [loader sendSynchronously];
```

However this code (1) uses the deprecated method objectLoaderForObject and (2) crashes saying `'Unable to find a routable path for object of type '(null)' for HTTP Method 'POST''`.

Comment: This isn't a good design. You should never make synchronous calls to a web server. If you need that information first, your app should handle the situations where there is not information (no internet connection for example), and when the information arrives (delegates or observers etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting aside the question of whether this is the ideal design for an iPhone application, I was able to accomplish what I was hoping using blocks.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[@"/api/users/" stringByAppendingString:[_userNameField text]] usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {

    loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {

        NSLog(@"Response: \n%@", [response bodyAsString]);
    };

    loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects) {

        APIUser *apiUser = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"user_id is %i", apiUser.user_id);


    };

    loader.onDidFailWithError = ^(NSError *error) {


            UIAlertView *badLoginAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"LOGIN_FAILED", nil)
                                                                   message:NSLocalizedString(@"BAD PASSWORD OR USERNAME", nil)
                                                                  delegate:self
                                                         cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [badLoginAlert show];           
    };
}];
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: +2 for the example with blocks, -1 for the design issue = +1

Comment: As I noted, this is not an ideal approach. In some situations where you can't change the backend APIs, this may help you out.

Comment: I agree with that it's not a good idea for a general application, but synchronous calls DO make your test units a lot easier to program.