# RestKit Best practices with the sendSynchronously method

Tags: restkit, synchronous

I am trying to load objects synchronously with RestKit and to do that I am using `[anObjectLoader sendSynchronously]` on a background thread. Then in the `RKObjectLoader` **didFinishLoad:** the application is currently stopping at the first line: `NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"RKObjectLoaderDelegate callbacks must occur on the main thread");`
Looking at the [documentation](http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKRequest.html#//api/name/sendSynchronously), the `sendSynchronously` method from the `RKRequest` class says that the request will be synchronously requested and a hydrated response object will be returned.
This is a snapshot of my code:

```
RKObjectLoader *anObjectLoader = [self.objectManager loaderWithResourcePath:resourcePath];
NSLog(@"Response: %@", [anObjectLoader sendSynchronously]);
```

On console:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[RKManagedObjectLoader didFinishLoad:], ...RestKit/Code/ObjectMapping/RKObjectLoader.m:423
```

Is it Ok to use **RestKit** with synchronous calls?
Are there better ways to send synchronous requests?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never make synchronous calls. Use the `send` method and catch the response using either delegates or block callbacks. Among other things, this method is optimized for network bandwidth usage and also handles threading correctly.

As an aside, the reason `RKObjectLoader` requires the main thread is because that is where your main object context is.

Comment: Thanks Paul. After reading other questions and answers on the web like [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325181/making-synchronous-calls-with-restkit), [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/restkit/synchronous/restkit/ozbyf9hbbHY/4FUGPiZKIXwJ), [3](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/restkit/synchronous/restkit/jUHOJOF4_nk/FULzlmEy14gJ) and so on I ended up agreeing with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this same question. I figured out how to send a synchronous call using blocks and it's actually quite nice. Basically you do whatever restkit call you were intending to do, but instead of setting the delegate to self, you use `usingBlock`. Then, within that block you can handle the various responses from your API call.

Block Example (APIUser is class I wrote that represents the current user):

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[@"/api/users/" stringByAppendingString:userName] usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {

    loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {

        NSLog(@"Response: \n%@", [response bodyAsString]);
    };

    loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects) {

        APIUser *apiUser = [objects objectAtIndex:0];    

    };

    loader.onDidFailWithError = ^(NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Response: \n%@", [response bodyAsString]);          
    };
}];
```

My original question and answer [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768287/how-to-make-a-synchronous-restkit-call).

Comment: I don't think this is a synchronous call?  It's just an async call that replaces the delegate calls, no?

Comment: I agree you are both right. However the solution is still helpful because using blocks you can guarantee that one call has finished successfully before issuing the next call. I wouldn't recommend it for nested blocks and calls, but I think there are some cases where it is helpful.